# How to flatten 2 meshes in meshlab

Tags: meshlab

I want to merge 2 meshes (mesh1, mesh2) with multiple texture materials into a single mesh (mesh3).
I load 2 meshes fine (the meshes are rendering and the texture materials are shown ok)

I then do "Filter -> Mesh Layer -> Flatten visible layers".

The structure of the resulting mesh looks fine but the texture materials disappear from the rendered model.

I export the merged mesh into .obj file, which creates a mesh3.obj, mesh3.mtl files

If I reopen mesh3.obj with meshlab, only the materials of the first original mesh (mesh1) show up and the portion of mesh2 is rendered with wrong textures from mesh1.

Note that the mesh1.mtl mesh2.mtl material names are similar (material1, material_2, ...) although the materials are different.
I tried renaming the materails of mesh2 but this does not help.

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug; see [issue #128](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/128). It should be fixed in the next release, or you can try the prerelease builds [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/cignoni/meshlab/build/artifacts) or [here](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/releases).

As a workaround, you can perform the same task in Blender by selecting both meshes and using the "Join" (Ctrl-J) command.